# How to perform a regression on 5 years of annual observations in eviews

Tags: regression, eviews

I am new to regression analysis so please excuse my ignorance.

I have collected 5 years of annual panel data, and I would like to regress this data on eviews but it is saying there is an insufficient amount of observations. Is there any way around this? I currently have 3 independent variables, 1 dependent and 3 control variables.

My suggestion is to just copy the same data down 4 times and regress that but I am thinking that may give me incorrect results.

Any help would be appreciated even if just to confirm that it isn't possible.

Comment: Just repeating your data is not acceptable. You don't give any eviews syntax (or equivalent). One of several crucial details here is whether you are trying to pool panels or not; there is no point anybody speculating because only you can make precise exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify which version of `Eviews` you are using, I assume that you are using latest version (7). In that case, if you have a panel data in an Excel file, you just have to import that as foreign file. Please see [here](http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?t=74&f=7) for details. I am also not sure whether there is any difference between control variable and independent variable. I think all control variables are independent variables but the reverse is not true.